# JQuery Show/Hide Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

So here is my dilemma. Been trucking on this Jquery extreme code here and I need help telling if a certain link is showing or not. Here is what I have.

The toggles:

```
<a href="#" id="visbilitybutton" class="button" title="Visible"><span class="icon icon84"></span></a>

<a href="#" id="visbilitybutton" class="button" title="Invisible"><span class="icon icon85"></span></a>
```

(notice the only thing that is different is the icon number) These need to toggle back and forth when someone clicks the #visbilitybutton. Not sure of the best way to do this and to capture what is selected as well.

The only code I have currently makes the toggle go one way, but doesn't go back when clicked again.

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#visbilitybutton').click(function() {
         $(this).replaceWith('<a href="#" id="visbilitybutton" class="button" title="Invisible"><span class="icon icon85"></span></a>');
    }); 
    });
```

Comment: why do you the same id..use class

Comment: @StoiaAlex that is how I am grabbing it with the jquery..

Comment: Even though jQuery lets you play with the DOM as though it's a string, don't. Take some time and learn about DOM manipulation *without jQuery* so you understand what's happening.

Comment: @greycode you should use class selectors in your jQuery code. Ids cannot be repeated in html document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you shouldn't have multiple identical `id` attributes on your page. Make `visibilitybutton` a class.

Anyways, you can use the jQuery `toggle()` function to specify what to do on each consecutive click:

```
$(".visibilitybutton").toggle(function(){
    $(this)
        .attr("title","Invisible")
        .find("span").toggleClass("icon84 icon85");
}, function(){
    $(this)
        .attr("title","Visible")
        .find("span").toggleClass("icon84 icon85");
});
```

If you want to be more efficient, you can do it all in one fell jQuery swoop like so, with some good techniques:

```
var vis = ["Invisible","Visible"];
$(".visibilitybutton").click(function(){
    var i = 0;
    $(this)
        .attr("title",vis[i])
        .find("span").toggleClass("icon84 icon85");
    i = (i==0)?1:0;
});
```

Even more so would be to make a class that hides the element when added to it and shows it when you remove it (a classname with `display:none` applied in the CSS works fine):

```
$(".visibilitybutton").click(function(){
    $(this)
        .toggleClass("hide")
        .find("span").toggleClass("icon84 icon85");
});
```

Comment: Hi @Purmou, I need to change the class from icon84 to icon85.. Would I use addClass?

Comment: Also, it starts out on the page as icon84.. Needs to change when clicked back and forth.

Comment: @greycode: Will there be 85 of these on the page? Does it need to work for each one?

Comment: No, just a single one. It starts at icon84.. When the user clicks it needs to change the class to icon85.. when they click again, it needs to go back to icon84 and so on

Comment: @greycode: I modified all three implementations to change the class of the inner span. I strongly recommend modifying your CSS and HTML to match the final example, as it's going to be the most efficient.

Comment: this seems to be working.. It just isn't adding the class back of icon85... It just removes the icon84 class

Comment: Can we do a replaceWith and pitch the classes?

Comment: @greycode: Yeah, that was my mistake. Try the updated code. **edit:** `replaceWith` is really an unnecessary fallback in a situation like this. `toggleClass` is quicker and easier to maintain.

Comment: nope, doesnt work. I've been using replacewith with most of the interface.. Could you give example with this?

Comment: I think its the code that initializes the images for the buttons.. No class stuff really works on this part I am working on. replaceWith seems to work like a charm though.

Comment: I'm not sure. Not worried about it anymore. Your code worked. I have another question you can answer if you'd like. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618240/add-html-based-on-toggle-jquery#comment15383949_11618240

Answer (score 1):

You need to have unique ids; therefore, you should select the items by class. You can use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to handle the consecutive clicks, and you can use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to handle the swapping of classes.

**HTML**:

```
<a href="#" class="button" title="Visible"><span class="icon icon84"></span></a>
<a href="#" class="button" title="Invisible"><span class="icon icon85"></span></a>
```

**Javascript**:

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
    $('.button').toggle(function() {
          var $button = $(this);

          $button.prop("title","Invisible");
          $button.find('.icon85').toggleClass('icon85', 'icon84');
    }, function() {
          var $button = $(this);

          $button.prop("title","Visible");
          $button.find('.icon85').toggleClass('icon84', 'icon85');
    });
 });
```

Comment: Can we do a replaceWith and pitch the classes?

Comment: You could but in my opinion classes are probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute is supposed to be unique to each element. Change the `id` attribute to the `class` attribute for each hyperlink.

Then, in your jQuery code, get the hyperlinks by their class name:

```
$('.visbilitybutton').click(function() {
    // code goes here
});
```

In your event handler, you should use test the `title` attribute, like so:

```
$('.visibilitybutton').click(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.attr("title") == "Visible")
        $this.attr("title", "Invisible").find("span")
            .removeClass("icon85").addClass("icon84");
    else
        $this.attr("title", "Visible").find("span")
            .removeClass("icon84").addClass("icon85");
});
```

Comment: @Purmou Good suggestion. I did so.

Comment: Can we do a replaceWith and pitch the classes? @jeff

Comment: @greycode - I'm not sure what you mean, but `replaceWith` would be less efficient than this method. For setting the icon classes right, though, you could do something like this: `.attr("class", "icon icon85")`. That would completely reset the class attribute, so you wouldn't need to use two method calls to get the class right.