# Add HTML based on Toggle Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, toggleclass

I have a toggle that was just made for a class I am getting to work. I need to add in hidden HTML based upon the toggle state.. Basically it needs to submit with the form with the state of the button.. Would this be the best way to grab it? I am posting the form also.

Here is what I have.. When I click the button, it adds the example text, but I need it to go away when I click again..

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 

    $(".visibilitybutton").click(function(){
        $(this)
            .toggleClass("hide")
            .find("span").toggleClass("icon84 icon85")
            $('.buttons_secondary').append("<input type='hidden'>");
    });

 });
```

Comment: Could you please be a little more thorough regarding what you are trying to accomplish and also include your html?

Comment: @JoshMein When I click the button.... It adds in html (doesn't matter what it is.) When I click it again, it removes it, and so on.

Comment: Where does buttons_secondary come from? I looked at your previous question and I am trying to understand the full picture of what you are trying to do. It seems to me that you are making it more difficult that it needs to be.

Comment: @JoshMein button secondary is where I want to append the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the html you append by id or class like so:

```
$('.buttons_secondary').append('<input id="hdf_Test" class="hidden" type="hidden" />');

// Remove by class
$('.buttons_secondary').find('.hidden').remove();

// OR Remove by id
$('.buttons_secondary').find('#hdf_Test').remove();
```

Based off of your previous question, I think you should try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('.button').toggle(function() {
          var $button = $(this);

          $button.prop("title","Invisible");
          $button.find('.icon85').toggleClass('icon85 icon84');
          $('.buttons_secondary').append('<input id="hdf_Test" class="hidden" type="hidden" />');
    }, function() {
          var $button = $(this);

          $button.prop("title","Visible");
          $button.find('.icon85').toggleClass('icon84 icon85');

          // Remove by class
          $('.buttons_secondary').find('.hidden').remove();

          // OR Remove by id
          $('.buttons_secondary').find('#hdf_Test').remove();
    });
 });
```

Comment: Wow @JoshMein, this is great! Only one small problem. After the third click, it removes the icon84/85 class completely. Once I click on it again, it comes back.

Comment: looks like it adds both classes then takes one off, then both off, then repeats.

Comment: toggleClass() swaps the classes. If icon84 is the original it swaps it with icon85 and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 

     $('.visibilitybutton').toggle(function() {
          var $button = $(this);

          $button.prop("title","Invisible");
          $button.find('span').removeClass('icon84').addClass('icon85');
          $('.buttons_secondary').append('<input id="visibility_setting" class="hidden" type="hidden" />');
    }, function() {
          var $button = $(this);

          $button.prop("title","Visible");
          $button.find('span').removeClass('icon85').addClass('icon84');

          // OR Remove by id
          $('.buttons_secondary').find('#visibility_setting').remove();
    });

 });
```

Comment: Why dont you try toggleClass instead of making two calls?